# Understanding hooks set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn about React Hooks, and encoutered a problem. I want to fetch data, display first 30 entries, and then in background fetch rest of data.
My logic:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const data = sortById(await fetch('url'));
            const prep = await prepareData(data, (pageNumber - 1) * elementsPerPage, pageNumber * elementsPerPage);
            setData(prep);
            setIsLoading(false);
            const backgroundData = await fetchMissingData(prep, elementsPerPage)
            setData(backgroundData);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    })();
}, [])
```

`data` is response from API, then I'm using it to add something to objects in prepareData - which itself is calling to another API, so when all requests are finished

```js
return Promise.all(result).then(done => {
    return done;
})
```

I'm getting array of objects, but only first 30 are filled with data that I need. When data is prepared I'm setting state of `data` and setting `loading` to false. In that moment data should be rendered(?) on the page. Then I'm fetching rest of data in the background, without fetching same data again(first 30 entries) and setting `data` again with every entry that I need in my application.

The problem is that data is being rendered after last `setData` - application is waiting for every fetch to finish.
Where is my mistake in logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState`, as in class components, it is async call (it does not act immediately but tells the component that it should render again with different context).

For example by that -

---

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
          setIsLoading(false);
          ...
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    })();
}, [])
```

---

`isLoading` never gonna be `true` in its component, cause at the same effect you give it both `true` and `false` (assuming your code will work line by line which not guaranteed with JS and you might encounter side effects).
The same thing goes to `data` because you calling `setData` twice

Because of that, you might consider split your effect into two effects, while `isLoading` is the flag for the second effect to run

---

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const data = sortById(await fetch('url'));
            const prep = await prepareData(data, (pageNumber - 1) * elementsPerPage, pageNumber * elementsPerPage);
            setData(prep);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
            setIsLoading(false);
            // in case there is e at first effect,second effect wont run
        }
    })();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
    (async function () {
        try {
                                                        //data now is equal to prep
            const backgroundData = await fetchMissingData(data, elementsPerPage)
            setData(backgroundData);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
        }
    })();
    setIsLoading(false);
   }
}, [isLoading, data])
```

---

In case `isLoading` flag is already used for UI rendering or something else and can't be the flag for second effect, you might create unique `isSecondEffectShouldRun` or something like so (using `data` itself will cause infinite loop...)

Wish it's helpful :)